# Failure installing build-essential from mirror repository

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, compiling, repository

I have a machine that needs network drivers to be built from source to get internet connectivity. In order to build the drivers, I need to install `build-essential` and friends.

I made a mirror repository using `apt-mirror`, copied it to a USB drive and attempted to install `build-essential` using that repository as the source for `apt`.

On the target machine, the `sources.list` file contains the following contents

`mike@target:~/Desktop/myrepo2$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb [arch=amd64] file:///home/mike/Desktop/myrepo2/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted`

When I attempt to install `build-essential`, I get the following error:

```
mike@target:~/Desktop/myrepo2$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 file:/home/mike/Desktop/myrepo2/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
Get:1 file:/home/mike/Desktop/myrepo2/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
Reading package lists... Done 
mike@target:~/Desktop/myrepo2$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:7.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:7.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.11) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

On the source machine, the following `mirror.list` file was used to generate the mirror repository, which was then copied over to a USB drive and from the USB drive to the target machine:

```
mike@source:~/Desktop/myrepo2$ cat /etc/apt/mirror.list
############# config ##################
#
set base_path    /home/mike/Desktop/myrepo2
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
```

What am I mising?

Comment: It looks like you are missing dependency packages (gcc). Did you try this command: `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: It didn't seem to help
`mike@target:~/Desktop/myrepo2$ sudo apt-get -f install
...
mike@target:~/Desktop/myrepo2$ sudo apt-get update
...
mike@target:~/Desktop/myrepo2$ sudo apt-get install build-essential

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:7.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:7.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.11) but it is not going to be installed`

All of these packages should be in `main` if I'm not mistaken, so I'm at a loss

Comment: Does your repository contain this packages: dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.11), g++ (>= 4:7.2),gcc (>= 4:7.2),  libc6-dev/libc-dev, make? Does `apt-cache search gcc`return a result? See here for the whole dependencies: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/build-essential; You could download all the debs packages above, install them using: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` As this packages have there own dependencies, you might need to download and install those aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this using aptitude. What seems to have happened was that the versions of some packages installed from the installation medium were newer than the dependencies of `build-essential`. I used `aptitude` to resolve the dependency problems.

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential
```